# Transformation of $t=0$ line in moving frame of reference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

How does $t=0$ transform into $t - vx/c^2 = 0$ if a frame of reference is moving as given in [here](http://www.lecture-notes.co.uk/susskind/special-relativity/lecture-1/lorentz-transformations/)?

It seems that the relativistic transformation is given by
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
x' \\ 
ct'
\end{bmatrix}= A\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ 
ct
\end{bmatrix} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} & -\frac{v}{c \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \\
 -\frac{v}{c \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \\
\end{array}
\right).\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ 
ct
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{x-t v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \\ 
\frac{c^2 t-v x}{c \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
\end{bmatrix}
  $$
I was wondering if the transformation is equivalent to measuring in new basis $A\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $A\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
1 \end{bmatrix}$ for an event?

Comment: Use Lorentz transformations .  The answer will come immediately .

Comment: @Dimension10 can't this be done without Lorentz transformations?

Comment: Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: the other transformation $x=0$ transforms into $x - vt = 0$ without Lorentz transformation.

Comment: The Lorentz transformation is *the* transformation characterizing the way coordinates appear in frames of differing motion. There is no other choice. How could there be?

Comment: @dmckee i was just wondering how it has been assumed on [this page](http://www.lecture-notes.co.uk/susskind/special-relativity/lecture-1/lorentz-transformations/#ln-axes-of-the-moving-frame) just for rotation of axes. The first equation is $x=vt$ which is the speed of ref. frame moving at constant speed and this line would represent new $x' = 0$ i.e. future of coordinates. I was just wondering how the second transformation of axes $t=0$ is rotated.